# Kyocera Mita KM-4030 Network Printer EXTREMELY slow to print from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, printer, network-printer

I have a network with 4 computers and 1 server. The server is running Windows 2008 x64 Standard (Domain Controller). IT IS NOT A PRINT SERVER. The four client computers print directly to the printer, using the IP address as the port. The port protocol is RAW, port 9100, and it doesn't matter if SNMP is enabled or disabled (it is slow either way).

Of the four computers, two are XP and two are Windows 7 32-bit. The XP computers have been here for much longer. The two XP computers print fine, but the two W7 computers print extremely delayed. When I say delayed, I mean that from the time you click "Print" to the time the printer even starts to warm up can take up to a minute.

There is not any antivirus software on the Windows 7 computers yet, only on the XP computers.

The driver used for the Kyocera install on the W7 computers is the Windows 7 version.

I am out of ideas and appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much headache, we caved and had the printer company come in. **They did a full hardware reset on the device** (reset all settings) and **updated the actual printer firmware** to the latest available.

Once we reconfigured it for our network and I reinstalled the printer drivers on all of the computers (since I had done so much tinkering and playing with settings), it started printing quickly again.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the print processor to WinPrint and data type to RAW?  Properties-Advanced-Print Processor.  Also check the queue on the system doing the printing when you send a job and see if you get any more info.  Things like size of the spooled job.

Comment: Also trying this if the new driver doesn't fix our problem. Thanks! (sorry about late response)

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this problem, and it is a bug in the Kyocera driver.  Don't use the standard driver or the one with the printer.  Download & instal the new version 8 Feb 2010.  In this client's case, printing took 1 minute 50 seconds to start, reduced to 5 seconds after driver upgrade.  Bruce

Comment: Trying this today. Thanks for the response (and sorry to everyone else for my very delayed response to this question.)

Comment: Bruce, do you have more specific information as to where I can aquire this driver? Kyocera does not list a new driver for my printer.

http://usa.kyoceramita.com/americas/jsp/Kyocera/download_center.jsp?pid=5057&pcat=10564&rcid=10009&rscid=10007